# 英語が残っている: レビューで「却下」を選択した後のダイアログ

Tags: バグ, 完了, 翻訳, 英語

URLを特定できず申し訳ないのですが
タイトルの通りです。

[image: 画像の説明をここに入力]

Comment: これが新しい文書になっているために、適用するつもりです。

Answer (score 2):

翻訳案：

**スパム又は荒らし**

この編集は製品の広告をするため、又は投稿の質を低下させるものです。

**投稿を改善していない**

この編集は投稿を読みやすくせず、探しやすくせず、より正確にせず、使いやすくしていません。変更された部分は不要又は投稿の品質を低下させています。

**不適切なタグ**

この編集は投稿のトピックを説明していないタグを追加しています。タグは質問の中身を示すためのものではなく、質問内容をより理解しやすくするためのものです。

**投稿者の意図と異なる**

この編集は投稿者の意図と異なります。大きな変更をしても、投稿者の意図を残すべきです。

**投稿者への返信**

投稿者への返信をするために編集しています。投稿者へのコメントはコメント又は回答にするべきです。

**悪用**

*投稿の質を低下させていると考える理由を書いてください*

Answer (score 1):

Transifexに反映しました（一部手を加えています）。

https://www.transifex.com/projects/p/stack-overflow-ja/translate/#ja/english/40289646?comment=%2F1638%2F

Answer (score 0):

[Transifex上で下記のストリングのまとめ](https://www.transifex.com/projects/p/stack-overflow-ja/translate/#ja/english/40289646?comment=http%3A%2F%2Fmeta.ja.stackoverflow.com%2Fquestions%2F1638%2F)

翻訳案：

**スパム又は荒らし**

この編集は製品の広告するため、又は投稿の質を低下する目的です。

**全く投稿を改善させない**

この編集は投稿を読みやすくせず、探しやすくせず、より正確にせず、使いやすくしないです。変更された部分は不要又は投稿を低下させました。

**不適切なタグ**

この編集は投稿のトピックを説明しないタグを追加させます。タグは質問の中身を示すことではなく、質問内容をより理解できる目的です。

**投稿者の意図と異なる**

この編集は投稿者の意図と異なります。大きな変更をしても、投稿者の意図を残すべきです。

**投稿者へのコメント**

この編集は投稿者へのコメントとして使っています。投稿者へのコメントはコメント又は回答にするべきです。

**悪用**

*この編集は投稿をなぜ悪くさせますか？*